# How to scale/transform graphics::plot() axes with any transformation, not just logarithmic (for Weibull plots)?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, weibull

I am building an R package to display Weibull plots (using `graphics::plot`) in R. The plot has a log-transformed *x*-axis and a Weibull-transformed *y*-axis (for lack of a better description). The two-parameter Weibull distribution can thus be represented as a straight line on this plot.

The logarithmic transformation of the *x*-axis is as simple as adding the `log="x"` parameter to `plot()` or `curve()`. How can I supply the *y*-axis transformation in an elegant way, so that all graphics-related plotting will work on my axis-transformed plot? To demonstrate what I need, run the following example code:

```
## initialisation ##
beta     <- 2;eta <- 1000
ticks    <- c(seq(0.01,0.09,0.01),(1:9)/10,seq(0.91,0.99,0.01))
F0inv    <- function (p) log(qweibull(p, 1, 1))
    # this is the transformation function
F0       <- function (q) exp(-exp(q))
    # this is the inverse of the transformation function
weibull  <- function(x)pweibull(x,beta,eta)
    # the curve of this function represents the weibull distribution 
    # as a straight line on weibull paper
weibull2 <- function(x)F0inv(weibull(x))
```

First an example of a Weibull distribution with `beta=2` and `eta=1000` on a regular, untransformed plot:

```
## untransformed axes ##
curve(weibull ,xlim=c(100,1e4),ylim=c(0.01,0.99))
abline(h=ticks,col="lightgray")
```

> [image: plot1]

This plot is useless for Weibull analysis. Here is my currently implemented solution that transforms the data with function `F0inv()` and modifies the *y*-axis of the plot. Notice that I have to use `F0inv()` on all *y*-axis related data.

```
## transformed axis with F0inv() ##
curve(weibull2,xlim=c(100,1e4),ylim=F0inv(c(0.01,0.99)),log="x",axes=F)
axis(1);axis(2,at=F0inv(ticks),labels=ticks)
abline(h=F0inv(ticks),col="lightgray")
```

> [image: plot2]

This works, but this is not very user-friendly: when the user wants to add annotations, one must always use `F0inv()`:

```
text(300,F0inv(0.4),"at 40%")
```

I found that you can achieve a solution to my problem using `ggplot2` and scales, but I don't want to change to a graphics package unless absolutely necessary since a lot of other code needs to be rewritten.

```
## with ggplot2 and scales ##
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
weibull_trans <- function()trans_new("weibull", F0inv, F0)
qplot(c(100,1e4),xlim=c(100,1e4),ylim=c(0.01,0.99),
    stat="function",geom="line",fun=weibull) + 
    coord_trans(x="log10",y = "weibull")
```

> [image: plot3]

I think that if I could dynamically replace the code for applying the logarithmic transformation with my own, my problem would be solved.

I tried to find more information by Googling "R axis transformation", "R user coordinates", "R axis scaling" without useful results. Almost everything I have found dealt with logarithmic scales.

I tried to look into `plot()` at how the `log="x"` parameter works, but the relevant code for `plot.window` is written in C – not my strongest point at all.

Comment: I will be interested if someone comes up with a better solution, but I think you've covered the relevant ground; I don't think you're going to do better than this -- outside of `ggplot2` I don't know of any systems for generic axis transformation.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. In the mean time, I came to the same conclusion, it looks like I will be forced to use ggplot2.

Answer (score 1):

While it doesn't appear to be possible in base graphics, you can make this function do what you want so that you can call it more simply:

```
F0inv    <- function (p) log(qweibull(p, 1, 1))
## this is the transformation function
F0       <- function (q) exp(-exp(q))

weibullplot <- function(eta, beta,
                        ticks=c(seq(0.01,0.09,0.01),(1:9)/10,seq(0.91,0.99,0.01)),
                        ...) {
  ## the curve of this function represents the weibull distribution 
  ## as a straight line on weibull paper
  weibull2 <- function(x)
    F0inv(pweibull(x, beta, eta))
  curve(weibull2, xlim=c(100, 1e4), ylim=F0inv(c(0.01, 0.99)), log="x", axes=FALSE)
  axis(1);
  axis(2, at=F0inv(ticks), labels=ticks)
  abline(h=F0inv(ticks),col="lightgray")
}

weibullplot(eta=1000, beta=2)
```